# I don't know why the url is not found

Tags: python, django

I have added a new action to the MeView called slack_user. But the api is not working and it says not found 404 error.

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class MeView(APIView):
"""
認証ユーザー
/users/me/
/users/me/slack_user/
"""
serializer_class = MyUserSerializer

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.serializer_class(request.user, context={'request': request})
    return Response(serializer.data)

def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.serializer_class(request.user, request.data, context={'request': request})
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)


@action(methods=['get', 'post', 'delete'], detail=True)
def slack_user(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = request.user

    ...

    if request.method == 'GET':
        slack_user = obj.get_slack_user()

        return Response({})


    if request.method == 'DELETE':
        obj.slack_users.all().delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.LoginView.as_view()),
    path('me/', views.MeView.as_view()),
]
```

/users/login and /users/me/ work but /users/me/slack_user says not found.
could you please help me with this error?

Comment: Why this should work? In url's there is no rout for `me/slack_user`.

Comment: You didn't specified `me/slack_user` into your **url_patterns**